# conservar un foliado diferente en php mysql cuando se insertan dos registros al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Dos usuarios o mas en distintas computadoras están llenando un formulario y dicho formulario les asigna un folio.

El folio se consulta de acuerdo al ultimo registrado en la BD y devuelve el siguiente folio a usar.

Ejemplo si ya esta el `00001` y actualmente estoy llenando un formulario me asigna el `00002` pero la otra persona en otra maquina también le asigna el `00002` antes de que guarde la información. Cuando guarda hace la inserción a la BD al primero que le de guardar le genera un folio `00002` y a mi el `00003` pero cuando consulto mi folio `00003` aparecen los datos de la persona que estaba llenando primero el formulario.

¿Existe alguna manera de reservar ese folio mientras no se de clic en guardar al registro en la BD con PHP?

Hago la aclaración de que yo no uso AutoIncrement en mi BD. Lo que hago es lo siguiente al consultar si ese folio ya existe:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('mb', $link);
$tmp1      = ("SELECT * FROM rprh06 ORDER BY FOLIO DESC");
$consulta1 = mysql_query($tmp1, $link);
$folio     = mysql_num_rows($consulta1);
mysql_free_result($consulta1);
if ($folio == 0) {
    $folio = $folio + 1;
} else {
    $folio = $folio + 1;
}
if (strlen($folio) == 1) {
    $folio = "0000" . $folio;
}
if (strlen($folio) == 2) {
    $folio = "000" . $folio;
}
if (strlen($folio) == 3) {
    $folio = "00" . $folio;
}
if (strlen($folio) == 4) {
    $folio = "0" . $folio;
}
```

Después de esto me muestra el siguiente folio a usar.

Comment: Con tu idea de reservar.. que pasa si quien tiene el folio dos, deja de usarlo, por cualquier motivo. Se aceptan saltos en tu ingreso?

Comment: Aparte esto = "SELECT * FROM rprh06 ORDER BY FOLIO DESC" cuando la base crezca, se va a volver un dolor muy grande. y por lo que veo, PHP no tiene una funcion para generar un pad automatico de ceros a la izquierda?

Comment: Lo ideal como bien dices que si ese folio no se va a usar, ya sea que el usuario lo cancele por el motivo que sea, lo ideal es re utilizar ese folio. ¿Existe algún modo?

Comment: si. pq no tomar el folio al momento de grabar, y no al momento de ingresar al formulario de alta?

Comment: Y si, analizando no debería hacer esto el 0001, este método ambiguo quizá no funcional me lo compartió un profesor de la carrera. Estoy diseñando esto y no tengo mucho conocimiento, conforme voy haciendo voy documentando, quizá hay algo que aun no he logrado encontrar para hacer mejor este proceso. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Y voy a ser agnostico del lenguaje con tu problema.

No deberias reservar un numero de folio con anticipacion, salvo que no te importe perder folios en el medio.

Si eso es un problema, entonces deberias guardar el folio al mismo tiempo que guardas los datos. Para evitar mayores problemas podrias tener una tabla con el maximo folio guardado, y asignar el nuevo dentro de una transaccion a todas las tablas al mismo tiempo, con lockeo exclusivo para evitar problemas de concurrencia.

Si perder folios en el medio no es problema, entonces tu aplicacion en si no deberia tener mayores problemas, y probablemente tengas un problema al guardar y por eso ves datos que no te corresponden. Igual recomendaria revisar que los datos en la BD estan correctos antes de seguir.

Aparte de esto, veo un par de problemas en el algoritmo (que no quiere decir si quiera que sea bueno, solo problemas en ese algoritmo).

Fijate que la linea

```
"SELECT * FROM rprh06 ORDER BY FOLIO DESC"
```

provoca que para buscar el folio que sigue tengas que hacer un full scan de la tabla.. para pocos registros esta bien.. pero en una aplicacion en serio, esto es muy malo.

Tambien, googleando esto: "padding zeros php"

encontre esto:

> str_pad
>
> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7) str_pad — Rellena un string hasta una
>   longitud determinada con otro string
>
> string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string
>   = " " [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]] )
>
> Esta función devuelve el string input rellenado por la izquierda, la
>   derecha, o en ambos lados hasta la longitud especificada. Si el
>   argumento opcional pad_string no se suministra, el input se rellena
>   con espacios, de lo contrario, se rellena con los caracteres de
>   pad_string hasta el límite.

con lo cual se resolveria la parte de rellenar con ceros.

Answer (score 1):

Lo haría de la siguiente forma:

Asignaría el numero de `folio` en el momento que lo guardes en la base de datos pero no pasarlo por el formulario.

Si no usas auto increment tienes que saber cual es el último `folio` antes de guardar los datos en la base de datos.

Esquema:

1. Recibir los `$datos_del_usario`
2. Pregunta a la base de datos cual es el último folio
3. Incrementar el `folio + 1`
4. Guardar todo junto en la base de datos: `$datos_del_usario` + `folio + 1`

**Nota aparte**: No uses `mysql_`!! Usa `mysqli` o `PDO` con sentencias preparadas para evitar los ataques [inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Answer (score 1):

Coincido en que lo mejor es que el folio lo agregues en el momento de insertar, no en el momento en que acceden al formulario.

Entonces según mi ejemplo, omite todo lo relacionado al folio en tu código y mira las siguientes opciones:

Puedes delegar esa tarea a mysql si tu campo folio es del tipo numérico (para hacer un +1 en el insert):

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla (folio, dato1, datoN)
 VALUES ( SUM( ( SELECT folio FROM mi_tabla) + 1), valor1, valorN )
```

Pero sino es numérico no puedes hacerle operaciones matemáticas, a menos que hagas un Cast:

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla (folio, dato1, datoN)
     VALUES ( SUM( ( CAST ( SELECT folio FROM mi_tabla) AS integer) + 1), valor1, valorN )
```

Sólo lo agregas en tu query original.

Creo que es lo mejor porque no acomplejas el código php.